# How to sort array based on key's Value?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, nssortdescriptor

I am Having Array called `inputArray` Like this.

```
(
    {
    "2016-01-21" =         {
        amount = 3978;
        date = "2016-01-20 18:30:00 +0000";
        "date-day" = 21;
        "date-month" = Jan;
        "date-year" = 16;
        units = 780;
    };
},
    {
    "2015-11-20" =         {
        amount = 7938;
        date = "2015-11-19 18:30:00 +0000";
        "date-day" = 20;
        "date-month" = Nov;
        "date-year" = 15;
        units = 1380;
    };
},
    {
    "2015-10-03" =         {
        amount = 13423;
        date = "2015-10-02 18:30:00 +0000";
        "date-day" = 03;
        "date-month" = Oct;
        "date-year" = 15;
        units = 2211;
    };
},
    {
    "2015-09-26" =         {
        amount = 4110;
        date = "2015-09-25 18:30:00 +0000";
        "date-day" = 26;
        "date-month" = Sep;
        "date-year" = 15;
        units = 800;
    };
},
    {
    "2015-08-03" =         {
        amount = 18300;
        date = "2015-08-02 18:30:00 +0000";
        "date-day" = 03;
        "date-month" = Aug;
        "date-year" = 15;
        units = 2950;
    };
},

)
```

From this array,I have to get `date-month` with highest amount.In this Example, index 5 contains `amount` value `18300` and the month of that index `Aug`.

How to do this?

Also i need to store that value to `NSString`.Also i need to sort this array based on amount Value and store that into new array.

Comment: Don't know why extra date key here, It would be so easy if that key doesn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the values that you want are dictionaries and you have an array of them such as:

```
NSDictionary *dict1 = @{
                            @"date" : @"2016-01-21",
                            @"values" : @{
                                    @"amount" : @3978,
                                    @"date" : @"2016-01-20 18:30:00 +0000",
                                    @"date-day" : @21,
                                    @"date-month" : @"Jan",
                                    @"date-year" : @16,
                                    @"units" : @780
                                    }

                            };

    NSDictionary *dict2 = @{
                            @"date" : @"2015-11-20",
                            @"values" : @{
                                    @"amount" : @7938,
                                    @"date" : @"2015-11-19 18:30:00 +0000",
                                    @"date-day" : @20,
                                    @"date-month" : @"Nov",
                                    @"date-year" : @15,
                                    @"units" : @1380
                                    }

                            };

    NSDictionary *dict3 = @{
                            @"date" : @"2015-10-03",
                            @"values" : @{
                                    @"amount" : @13423,
                                    @"date" : @"2015-10-02 18:30:00 +0000",
                                    @"date-day" : @3,
                                    @"date-month" : @"Oct",
                                    @"date-year" : @15,
                                    @"units" : @2211
                                    }

                            };

    NSDictionary *dict4 = @{
                            @"date" : @"2015-09-26",
                            @"values" : @{
                                    @"amount" : @4110,
                                    @"date" : @"2015-09-25 18:30:00 +0000",
                                    @"date-day" : @26,
                                    @"date-month" : @"Sep",
                                    @"date-year" : @15,
                                    @"units" : @800
                                    }

                            };

    NSDictionary *dict5 = @{
                            @"date" : @"2015-08-03",
                            @"values" : @{
                                    @"amount" : @18300,
                                    @"date" : @"2015-08-02 18:30:00 +0000",
                                    @"date-day" : @3,
                                    @"date-month" : @"Aug",
                                    @"date-year" : @15,
                                    @"units" : @2950
                                    }

                            };

    NSArray *array = @[dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4, dict5];
```

You can sort the array using a comparator:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *obj1, NSDictionary *obj2) {
    NSNumber *amount1 = obj1[@"values"][@"amount"];
    NSNumber *amount2 = obj2[@"values"][@"amount"];

    // Sort in descending order so highest number is first
    return [amount2 compare:amount1];
}];
```

Since the array is sorted on the amount in descending order, you can get the first dictionary from the sorted array and get whatever value you want out of that

```
NSString *dateWithMax = sortedArray.firstObject[@"values"][@"date-month"];
NSLog(@"%@", dateWithMax);
```